# editing / splitting / saving data in a text file

Tags: perl, unix, matlab, octave

I have a text file called playlist.pls which is dynamically created, and in the text file I have thousands of lines that look like this:

```
File000001=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0001.wav 
File000002=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0002.wav 
File000003=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0003.wav 
File000004=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0004.wav 
File000005=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0005.wav 
File000006=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0006.wav 
File000007=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0007.wav 
File000008=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0008.wav 
File000009=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0009.wav 
File000010=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0010.wav etc...
```

I need to have the data in the text file split into several different files.
example:

```
The play1.pls file would contain:
File000001=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0001.wav 
File000002=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0002.wav 
File000003=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0003.wav 

The play2.pls file would contain:
File000004=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0004.wav 
File000005=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0005.wav 
File000006=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0006.wav 

The play3.pls file would contain:
File000007=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0007.wav 
File000008=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0008.wav 
File000009=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0009.wav 

The play4.pls file would contain:
File000010=/home/ubu32sc/Documents/octave/pre/wavefn_0010.wav etc...
```

What's the best way to go about doing this I was thinking about using octave/matlab to do this but I think this would be over kill and resource intensive to run a for loop on a text file with 10's of thousands of lines.  Is grep or perl the proper thing to use and or should I use another type of program? and if so how could I do this with it?

I'm using Ubuntu 32 10.04 6 gig ram
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentionned it, Matlab / Octave seems to be an overkill if you just want to split a text file into multiple files.

There are a thousand ways to do this (espcially on a unix system) so just pick yours.

One of the possibilities is to use [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) which goes like this:

```
split --lines=3 file prefix
```